# How do I configure a Calendar view on custom entity with a date field?

Tags: calendar, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm currently extending a Dynamics 365 Customer Service app. We have created a new entity that has a date field. We would like to show a custom view for that entity that renders the records in a calendar based on the date field per item.

This seems like a trivial task yet I cannot find any information on how to achieve this. Does it require an iFrame with an Asp.Net custom page?

Please provide developer guidance on the correct approach to achieving this.

Comment: Can you get the url of that calendar, we had somewhat similar for service calendar. We took url of service calendar and filtered it based on some resources. This was added as an Iframe. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: There’s currently no calendar.

Comment: Curious question, does my previous comment make any sense in your scenario.

Comment: @BrianScott did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Credit for this answer goes to [Tip #1206: View any Dynamics 365 record on a calendar](https://crmtipoftheday.com/1206/view-any-dynamics-365-record-on-a-calendar/)

Keep in mind that this solution **only works if you use unified interface**. If you don't, I'll show you how you can achieve it by the end of this post.

1. Go to Settings->Customization->Customize the System
2. Open the configuration for the entity that you want to use the calendar control (Opportunities in our example)
3. Click the View tab
4. Click “Add Control” and select the calendar control.
5. Click the dot for every interface from which you want the calendar control to be available.

[image]

You will then need to map the calendar fields to the desired values. For example, if you want the date to be based on estimated close date, you would select estimatedclosedate for the Start date.

[image]

If your project already uses unified interface you have your solution by now. Otherwise, if you still use classic mode and want a unified interface view just for this case in particular follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings -> My Apps;
2. Click Create a New App;
3. Give it a name and click done;
4. Configure your sitemap, the important part here is to choose your entity in the SubArea.
5. Save and Publish your sitemap;
6. Save, Validate, Publish and Play your App. And voilá you will a view similar to this one:

[image]